# sqlsrv access database and tables that have spaces in their names in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I can access database and tables that don't have spaces in their names but when they do I can't.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM [LoLDatabase].[dbo].[Champ Stats]"; 
^ has no errors but returns nothing
$result = "SELECT * FROM [LoLDatabase].[dbo].Items";
^Works

echo $obj->Cost.'<br />';  
^works

echo $obj->Item Name.'<br />';  
^Does not work

nor do these...
echo $obj->Item_Name.'<br />'; 

$colName = "[Item Name]";
echo $obj->$colName.'<br />';  

echo $obj->[Item_Name].'<br />';
```

So is my only hope to change the names in my SQL Manager?

Comment: How about `$obj['Item Name']`? I can't see anything wrong with the first select, so very strange if it doesn't return the rows that are in the table.

Comment: Perhaps the spaces are not really spaces, but some other unprintable character.  Or, you have spaces at the end of the name too.

Comment: No they are spaces as set in my MSSQL Manager which adds [] to identifiers with spaces. so my name becomes [my name]. No spaces after. $obj['Item Name'] does not seem to me php friendly as it breaks my file returning nothing but an empty page.

Comment: Have you tried $obj->{Item Name} ?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT [Item Name] + ' ' as ItemName 
FROM [LoLDatabase].[dbo].Items;
```

so it will have to do for now.