# Codeigniter connect database that contain spaces in database name

Tags: sql-server, database, codeigniter

i wanna ask, why codeigniter cant conect to the database if the database contain a 'spaces' character, below is sample code that connection work like a charm.

```
$db['posko_db']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['posko_db']['username'] = 'root';
$db['posko_db']['password'] = '';
$db['posko_db']['database'] = 'database';  <---- without spaces
$db['posko_db']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['posko_db']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['posko_db']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['posko_db']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['posko_db']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['posko_db']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['posko_db']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['posko_db']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['posko_db']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['posko_db']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['posko_db']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and here the sample code that connection cant work

```
$db['posko_db']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['posko_db']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['posko_db']['password'] = '';
    $db['posko_db']['database'] = 'data base';  <---- with spaces
    $db['posko_db']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
    $db['posko_db']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['posko_db']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['posko_db']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['posko_db']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['posko_db']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['posko_db']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['posko_db']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['posko_db']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['posko_db']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['posko_db']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

i was trying to using many way, and still not working, anyone can help? 
thanks.

Comment: It is working for MySQL databases.

Comment: let me try, hold on a sec.

Comment: its working for MySQL im creating database with a name 'data base' and connecttion established.

Comment: If so please check \system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php, may be you can fix the problem.

Comment: Check this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087730/sqlsrv-access-database-and-tables-that-have-spaces-in-their-names-in-php

Comment: it still not working

Comment: i wass trying to replace 'data base' with [data base] / "[data base]" / '[data base]' / [data base]+ its still not working

Comment: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
if i try '[data base]'

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SQL server, may some other users will help you.

Comment: @DwiAbriyanto its over rule,there will be no spaces in DB,Table and Field name of any database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no space(s) allowed in database name,table name or field name,so the following code will never work because it is over rule.

```
 $db['posko_db']['database'] = 'data base';  <---- with spaces -->
```

It should be like this,

```
$db['posko_db']['database'] = 'database';
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me: Change system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php

```
function db_connect($pooling = false)
{
    // Check for a UTF-8 charset being passed as CI's default 'utf8'.
    $character_set = (0 === strcasecmp('utf8', $this->char_set)) ? 'UTF-8' : $this->char_set;

    $connection = array(
        'UID'               => empty($this->username) ? '' : $this->username,
        'PWD'               => empty($this->password) ? '' : $this->password,           
        'ConnectionPooling' => $pooling ? 1 : 0,
        'CharacterSet'      => $character_set,
        'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => 1
    );
    // If the username and password are both empty, assume this is a
    // 'Windows Authentication Mode' connection.
    if(empty($connection['UID']) && empty($connection['PWD'])) {
        unset($connection['UID'], $connection['PWD']);
    }
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($this->hostname, $connection);
            sqlsrv_query($conn,'USE ['.$this->database.']');
    return $conn;
}
```

Original:

```
function db_connect($pooling = false)
{
    // Check for a UTF-8 charset being passed as CI's default 'utf8'.
    $character_set = (0 === strcasecmp('utf8', $this->char_set)) ? 'UTF-8' : $this->char_set;

    $connection = array(
        'UID'               => empty($this->username) ? '' : $this->username,
        'PWD'               => empty($this->password) ? '' : $this->password,
        'Database'          => $this->database,
        'ConnectionPooling' => $pooling ? 1 : 0,
        'CharacterSet'      => $character_set,
        'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => 1
    );

    // If the username and password are both empty, assume this is a
    // 'Windows Authentication Mode' connection.
    if(empty($connection['UID']) && empty($connection['PWD'])) {
        unset($connection['UID'], $connection['PWD']);
    }

    return sqlsrv_connect($this->hostname, $connection);
}
```